# sending database date to a html form

Tags: html, forms

i want to create a script that allows a user to create a challenge by answering some predefined questions, once they answer the questions and submit the form, a database entry is created which in-turn post back to the website on a different page. Now other users see the challenge that was created and have a option to accept. My question is , how do i create a page that allows the challenges to populate the page and stay on the page until someone accepts the challenge, i guess its the same idea as a que,im stuck at the html form that i want to use to post the questions back to, i can get one query into the form but then the next query over-rights the first one instead of creating a list of challenges,

Comment: Well, What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow. I feel like you're stuck at looping the DB results onto the webpage. But, again, I'm not sure. Try to improve your question by adding code examples, and perhaps an illustration of what you're trying to accomplish. Also, it may help to include tags for your server-side language (PHP?) and database (MySQL?)

Comment: i apologize, im quite new at php and i don't know exactly how to express what i want to do although in my mind i know. i have no code yet but let me try and clarify :

Comment: : A user creates a challenge via the create challenge form, the challenge details creates a entry in the database, then with Mysql SELECT function i retrieve the created challenge details and insert the details back to a table/form which will be in a "challenges" area of site , this form will only have a "accept" function,the fields are hardcoded with the challenge details pulled from DB .

Comment: : A user creates a challenge via the create challenge form, the challenge details creates a entry in the database, then with Mysql SELECT function i retrieve the created challenge details and insert the details back to a table/form which will be in a "challenges" area of site , this form will only have a "accept" function,the fields are hardcoded with the challenge details pulled from DB .

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax and give every challenge unique id and let ajax check if someone accept challenge  
*Table Name: Challenge
**Col1: ChallengeID
**Col2: User01
**Col3: User03
let ajax check every 1-3 seconds if `User03` not null then someone accept challenge

Comment: how will ajax determine if a challenge was accepted from the client side ?

Comment: to be sure your page will have challenge ID by post or get right ?